# Binding environment and function scopes in R

Tags: r

I wish to define a function that uses variables in the scope/environment in which it is called (another function), and not the environment in which it is defined. How do I specify the appropriate environment in R for the function call?

```r
x <- 5
g <- function() x^2
g() # This will work okay
```

but this will be complain that `x` cannot be found.

```r
rm(x) # Remove x from the global environment
f <- function(x) {
  g()
}
f(2) # This will complain that it can't find x.
```

I'd like to avoid defining the function `g` within `f`, and use something like, `evalq(g, envir=environment(f))` as the call. It would also be helpful for someone to explain the lower level reasons of why this doesn't work as expected as well. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `g <- function(x) x^2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `f` set the environment of `g` to that within `f`.  See line marked ## .

```
g <- function() x^2
f <- function(x) {
  environment(g) <- environment() ##
  g()
}
f(2)
```

Another approach is to define `g` like this:

```
g <- function() eval.parent(substitute(x^2))
f <- function(x) {
  g()
}
f(2)
```

A third approach is to define `g` in `f`:

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- function() x^2
  g()
}
f(2)
```